# How to configure Hazelcast Map via YAML

Tags: yaml, hazelcast

In XML the default and named map configuration would look like this `<map name="default">` `<map name="*-mycustommaprule">` respectively

What does that translate to in YAML?

Default map in the sample config file is:

```
map:
  default:
    in-memory-format: BINARY
```

Which of below is correct?

```
map:
  *-mycustommaprule:
    in-memory-format: BINARY
```

or

```
map:
  name: "*-mycustommaprule"
    in-memory-format: BINARY
```

Or neither...?

Comment: Rafal's answer is correct. One more hint: if you are stuck with the syntax of YAML, you can use JSON any time. They are compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version is:

```
map:
  "*-mycustommaprule":
    in-memory-format: BINARY
```

So the format is always the same as for the `default` map. The only thing is that you use special char `*`, so you need to use a quotation.